# Trouble with Android apk

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk

I have an app that I uploaded to the Google Play Store. It stops running once downloaded or can't be downloaded at all.  I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with my manifest as that's the error.  I'm going to add my app release apk and manifest file.

Asking if someone could help me find the issue, it shouldn't be a terrible error, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks.

Manifest file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.Houston_Rockets_Team_App">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:debuggable="false"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode">
    <activity
        android:name="com.Houston_Rockets_Team_App.Houston_Rockets_Team_App.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.Houston_Rockets_Team_App.Houston_Rockets_Team_App.PlayersActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!--    <data android:mimeType="image/png" /> -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.Houston_Rockets_Team_App.Houston_Rockets_Team_App.StaffActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!--    <data android:mimeType="image/png" /> -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.Houston_Rockets_Team_App.Houston_Rockets_Team_App.Settings" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!--    <data android:mimeType="image/png" /> -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.Houston_Rockets_Team_App.Houston_Rockets_Team_App.AboutActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!--    <data android:mimeType="image/png" /> -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.Houston_Rockets_Team_App.Houston_Rockets_Team_App.EditPrefs" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!--    <data android:mimeType="image/png" /> -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here's the apk, I'm hoping it can be opened.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18VT9Gl4adwBGuMa_omGWtjf0IM4Rc0RD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: -Run your app in debug mode in emulator or in device and put the error here that which error you got.
-**android:debuggable="true"** create signed apk run into device connect with studio and check what error you got, put your error here.
sometimes error generate in only signed apk. so set debuggable true into manifest.

Answer (score 0):

-I found your bug and its mainActivity not found error raise.
-***Please check your MainActivity path into the manifest and set right classpath into the manifest that will solve your error.***

Comment: Should i be adding something new into the MainActivity part of the manifest or simply modifying the android:name part in the manifest?

Comment: set proper classpath of the activity or check the path of your activity ,compiler doesn't find the class.

Comment: ***.Houston_Rockets_Team_App***  I think issue is here you place 2 times this package so that error raise. remove one time from class path like below code:
***<activity
        android:name="com.Houston_Rockets_Team_App.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>***

if this works apply this changes in all class path in manifest.